# Mac not accepting Password even with Password Resets

Tags: macos, password

My MacBook Pro stopped accepting my password. I have reset the password several times by restarting with Command+R, but every time my username is prompted to enter a password, the new passwords are refused.

I am able to log in under the separate Admin login and have made all the available changes to try and login automatically but no matter what is done, switching to my usual username requires a password and the password is refused even when correct.

All my files are under this username so I need to access this specific login, but it seems I have exhausted all the information I am able to find on how to fix this. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you change password of your standard account while being logged in as admin?

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure all the data is backed up and then make a new account.

Test that new account - one possibility that comes to mind is that there is a keyboard mismatch when entering the password at login.

If all is then well, install the data from the backup and proceed as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this works, but I've seen this issue on Macs and resetting NVRAM fixes it.  Reset instructions are on Apple's site:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063